# python pandas filter columns for true, false and both

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am currently trying to filter a pandas df with certain boolean columns for true, false and both types within a loop.

For better explanation let's say we have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'a': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
'b': [True, True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False], 
'c': [True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, False], 
'd': [35, 59, 12, 2, 19, 24, 33, 5, 11]
})
```

What I want to do now is loop over the both boolean columns like so:

```
loops = [[True, True], [True, any], [any, True], [any, any]]

for loop in loops:
df[(df['b'] == loop[0]) & (df['c'] == loop[1])]['d'].sum()
```

Unfortunately using `any` is not working, as well as `bool`.

As anyone an idea how that could be archived?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `any` doesn't make sense here, this is a function not a generic term that pandas would understand.

Why not using a `set` for your conditions?

```
T = {True}
F = {False}
ANY = {True, False}
NONE = {}

loops = [[T, T], [T, ANY], [ANY, T], [ANY, ANY]]

for loop in loops:
    x = df[df['b'].isin(loop[0]) & df['c'].isin(loop[1])]['d'].sum()
    print(loop, x)
```

Output:

```
[{True}, {True}] 64
[{True}, {False, True}] 135
[{False, True}, {True}] 116
[{False, True}, {False, True}] 200
```

##### Alternative using functions

If you create custom functions, make sure they are vectorized.

```
def istrue(x):
    return x == True  # or just "return x" if you only have booleans

def isfalse(x):
    return x == False # not using "~ x" to make the function generic

def isany(x):
    return x | True

def isnone(x):
    return x & False

loops = [[istrue, istrue], [istrue, isany], [isany, istrue], [isany, isany]]

for loop in loops:
    x = df[loop[0](df['b']) & loop[1](df['c'])]['d'].sum()
    print([x.__name__ for x in loop], x)
```

Output:

```
['istrue', 'istrue'] 64
['istrue', 'isany'] 135
['isany', 'istrue'] 116
['isany', 'isany'] 200
```

Comment: I added an alternative using functions

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the same solution as mozway first. But for your specific example, I think just the simple solution is more readable and actually shorter:

```
print(df[df['b'] & df['c']]['d'].sum())
print(df[df['b']]['d'].sum())
print(df[df['c']]['d'].sum())
print(df['d'].sum())
```

Or slightly more versatile

```
conditions = [df['b'] & df['c'], df['b'], df['c'], slice(len(df))]
for condition in conditions:
    print(df[condition]['d'].sum())
```

Comment: I guess OP needs to be able to generalize to an arbitrary number of columns and list of conditions. Otherwise I agree that hardcoding the operations is more straightforward.